# Predict the first observations of a time series when order of the model is higher

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, autoregressive

Suppose you have you have a time series with 365 observations, one for each day of the year, and you split the first 183 rows in training set and the latest 182 in test set.

Suppose you create an AR (autoregressive model), and you set the order of the model to 4. So you will have

$$y(t) = a_1y(t-1)+a_2y(t-2)+a_3y(t-3)+a_4y(t-4)$$

In a situation like this, is it possible to do predictions on the first observation of the test set? That basically is the 184<sup>th</sup> row

I think no, because we do not have $y(t-1),\dots,y(t-4)$ but we have only $y(t) = $ value of 184<sup>th</sup> observation.

So, the first row we can predict is 188<sup>th</sup>, right? Because:

- $y(t-1) = $ value of 187<sup>th</sup> row
- $y(t-2) = $ value of 186<sup>th</sup> row
- $y(t-3) = $ value of 185<sup>th</sup> row
- $y(t-4) = $ value of 184<sup>th</sup> row

I think that until now is right. Correct me if I am wrong.
But if I want to predict the obs. 184, the first one of the test set, is there any way? I mean, without decreasing the order of the model from 4 to 1 for example.

Comment: You can use data[179:183] . or?

Comment: @user2120 no because they belong to the training set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a situation like this, is it possible to do predictions on the first observation of the test set?

Yes, it is. This is done routinely in time series cross validation and is not a problem. You are not leaking any relevant information between the training and the validation set this way. See e.g. Hyndman and Athanasopoulos ["Forecasting: Principles and Practice (3r edition)"](https://otexts.com/fpp3/tscv.html). See some more in Hyndman's blog posts ["Time series cross-validation: an R example"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscvexample/) and ["Cross-validation for time series"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/) and his and coauthors' paper referenced therein.

Also note that your AR(4) model lacks the error term at the end.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know it lacks the error term at the end, I wrote in that way for simplicity